# Mybatis delete returns negative value. Why is that?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I have the following mybatis mapper and interface definitions:

```
<delete id="deleteTestSet">
        DELETE FROM projects_test_sets
         WHERE project_id = #{testSet.project.id}
           AND id = #{testSet.id}
    </delete>
```

and

```
interface ITestSetRepository {

    Integer deleteTestSet(@Param("testSet") TestSet testSet);

}
```

When calling from the code:

```
  Integer result = testSetRepository.deleteTestSet(testSet);
```

I get the result value -2147482646 being returned, no matter if the delete query deletes 0, 1 or multiple entries.

Any idea why is this ?

The DB is MySQL 5.7.19-17

Mybatis version: 3.4.6

Thanks

Comment: I think the data you got is `-2147483648`(which is Integer.MIN_VALUE) rather than `-2147482646`, this return value not appear on my side

Comment: The value i posted initially is correct. Initially i had the same impression that i'm getting a signed integer, but looking closer I noticed that the value is way off. Anyhow the problem seem to come from my SQL session configuration. you can find more details here: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1362

Answer (score 2):

When mybatis `BATCH` executor is used operations are not executed immediately. Mybatis only records the fact that such operation should be executed and their execution is delayed. That's why the mapper method cannot return the actual number of records affected. It always returns hardcoded negative constant instead.

In order to get the actual number of affected rows you can force the batch execution using the method annotated with `@Flush`:

```
@Flush
List<BatchResult> flush();
```

It would return the result for every operation executed in a batch so far.